# Is it possible to get a reference to the raw image buffer for system.drawing.graphics class?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm trying to render an image from an unmanaged control on to a WPF window. So far I'm able to get a working graphics object (because I'm able to overlay image to the unmanaged control). What I'm hoping to do is the opposite, which is to capture image from graphics object and save as a imagesource for another control.

```
var graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(hwndPtr);//From image unmanaged source
graphics.(??) // save to bitmap or any image format
```

If not possible to save an image with graphics object directly, would it be possible to get a raw reference to the image buffer of the graphics object? (For use with code like below)

```
var bmp = (InteropBitmap)Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromMemorySection(
                                  hwntPtr,120,120,format,stride,0);
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: I'm guessing you are attempting this as a work around to the WPF airspace problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is slightly modified code from an MSDN forum article but it should do the trick as far as getting a System.Drawing.Bitmap from a System.Drawing.Graphics object.

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]

internal static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hDest, int nDstX, int nDstY, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hSrc, int nSrcX, int nSrcY, uint BitBltOperation);

Bitmap SaveAsBitmap(Graphics gxSrc, int sizeX, int SizeY)
{
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(sizeX, sizeY);
    Graphics gxDst = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
    IntPtr hSrc = gxSrc.GetHdc();
    IntPtr hDst = gxDst.GetHdc();
    BitBlt(hDst, 0, 0, sizeX, sizeY, hSrc, 0, 0, 0xcc0020); // SourceCopy operation
    gxDst.ReleaseHdc(hDst);
    gxSrc.ReleaseHdc(hSrc);
    gxDst.Dispose();
    return bm;
}
```

[Original article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/c320e6a3-cb99-4c3e-bf68-6b23c56d6645)

Comment: I'm a little confused about why you want to do this in WPF; it seems circumventive.  If you clarify your question a bit there may be a better solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works :D  You are correct I'm trying to work around the airspace issue. Unfortunately the source for the images is a native app I have to work with (client requirements). If there was another way that is more performant I'd be interested. Another thing I as looking to explore the route taken by fraps (dll injection) but that's alot more complex.   Again thank you.

Comment: Great :).  In that case would you mind selecting this as the accepted answer?  I'd hugely appreciate it!